# Detect a hyper link by jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a html page with jquery. I wan to detect a link. Please read the below codes:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<a name="anchor">Anchor</a>
```

Here 1st code is a link. But 2nd code isn't a link. My jquery code:

```
<script>
$("a").click(function(){
alert("You clicked on a link");
});
</script>
```

The problem is if I click on both the first two codes then it alerts that I have clicked on a link. Any idea to detect a actual link? Please help me anyone!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Has Attribute selector:](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```
$("a[href]").click(function() {
    // Do something.
});
```